# How do I visualize this CNN Keras mode?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a Keras CNN model and am having trouble trying to visualize it. I am using Jupyter Notebook on Windows.

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(410796, 100, input_length=100))
# convolutional layer
model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

The model summary:

[image]

I have been trying to use the following:

```
 from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
 plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

However, I receive a message saying "('You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) ', 'for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.')"

I have tried to install GraphViz and even attempted to follow other StackOverflow questions. However, nothing seems to work

My question is: Is there any other good visualization techniques Or does someone know how to fix the GraphViz problem?

Comment: 1. What OS are you using (Windows, Linux, ...)?  2.Is Graphviz installed? (type this: dot -V)

Comment: You can save the Keras model with `model.save('path/to/location')` and use [netron](https://netron.app/)  to visualize it.